# How do I manually install VMware Tools?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, installation, vmware-player

I installed Ubuntu with VMware Player on my Windows 7 system.

For some reason VMware Player cannot get the Vmware Tools files from the Internet, possibly a connection problem due to firewall limitations. I want to get the VMware Tools files in a compressed format if possible, then manually install it. A few questions:

1. Is there a link where I can download the VMware Tools files?
2. To which folder should I uncompress the contents?
3. How do I install it manually?

I'm using VMware Player on a Windows 7 system. As you know, Ubuntu runs on a virtual disk, and to copy files on this disk I guess I have to use VMware Tools - however I don't have it already! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Download them from [VMware Tools Operating System Specific Packages](http://www.vmware.com/download/packages.html).

Installation, from [VMware Tools for Linux Guests](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/new_guest_tools_ws.html#1008207) :

```
su -
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
cd /tmp
tar zxf /mnt/vmware-linux-tools.tar.gz
umount /mnt
cd vmware-tools-distrib
./vmware-install.pl
exit
```

In an X terminal, launch the VMware Tools background application:

```
vmware-toolbox &
```

Comment: ok, but how do i install them? and, which one should i download? there is a bunch of files at that link

Comment: That's true, the download link is missing at that address! So I will tell you how I did this: I downloaded the trial version of VMware Workstation and did this with it. The Player is really full of bugs and is only good for the most elementary stuff.

Comment: In some situations (e.g. Ubuntu or Lubuntu) you actual have to eject the CD from inside the guest OS, then select the "VMWare Tools Installation" from the VMWare host and then follow the instructions above.